# Flash won't fire after first shot

Tags: nikon, flash

I have a Nikon D7200. I set the camera up to take a 3 pictures at 2 second intervals using the built in self-timer. The flash will fire the first time but not the second or third. I know the flash has enough time to recharge, since if I shoot in burst mode the flash will fire about every second. Is there another setting I need to configure to get the flash to fire on each interval of the self-timer?

**Edit:**
I'm using a Neewer NW-985N flash set to TTL.

Comment: Recycling within 1 second typically means the flash has to be well below full power. Most speedlights take 3-7 seconds for a full-power recycle between bursts. The fact that you're using TTL makes it difficult to tell what power level is set. When you did your burst test, was it under identical lighting conditions?

Comment: I was using the flash outdoors with noon time direct sun. The flash was just being used as a fill and was set to lower power.

Comment: And the flash is on the camera's hotshoe?

Comment: @inkista that is correct.

Comment: If you manually push the shutter button at 2 second intervals does the flash fire all three times?

Comment: @MichaelClark Yes, if I manually push the shutter it fires each and every time. It has something to do with the self-timer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are under the same lighting conditions and have the same settings selected when manually pushing the shutter button each time (the flash always fires) as you do when using the self timer (the flash only fires once), then it appears that the limitation of only the first frame firing the flash when using the internal flash (see pages 70 and 148 of the D7200 User Manual) also applies to an external flash when using the self timer. Page 70 also seems to indicate that only one frame will be exposed. YMMV.

The instructions for *Interval Timer Photography* on page 217 of the [D7200 User Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/BLXYI00h4qaR01fiDuZ53t0rd756/D7200UM_NT(En)02.pdf) specifically exclude using the self-timer with the interval timer feature.

> **Before Shooting**
>   Select a release mode other than self timer and **Mup** when using the
>   interval timer.

There is a built in 3-second delay when pressing the shutter button to start the interval timer when *Now* is selected in the *Start Options* (p.220) of the *Interval Timer* menu.

Your D7200 also has an option for *Time Lapse Photography* (p.171) which does seem to allow the flash to fire with every frame (p.176).

Answer (score 1):

With the internal flash?  Not with the internal flash.  The internal flash will fire only one time in any continuous shutter mode, including self timer.  See D7200 manual page 70 and also 144.

You can however use a hot shoe flash the way you want, but not the internal flash.

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified. I'm using a hot shoe flash set to TTL.

Comment: I don't have a NW-985N anymore, but a Neewer VK-750II (is from a different manufacturer) and others too will do the three shots at 2 second intervals with the D800 self timer.  If it can recycle, I think no reason it shouldn't.  But the internal flash is a definite exception.

Comment: Curious, but as a test, if you do not use the self timer, and instead just push the shutter button three times, two seconds apart, does the flash fire then?  It should of course.    I keep thinking of the flash still  being triggered by a switch on the shutter, but I suppose everything is relayed through the CPU today..

Comment: Yes, if I manually push the shutter at the two second intervals it fires each and every time.